# Returning the response back to AJAX and showing the message

Tags: php, ajax

I'am trying to get the results from the PHP page to the AJAX so that the AJAX knows if it's successful or not.

I'am very new to AJAX so not sure if am correct or not.

MY AJAX is as follows:

```php
if ($("#register_form").valid()) {
    var data1 = $('#register_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "register.php",
        data: data1,captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse(),
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            //check if response is true

            if (msg == true) {
                $('.messagebox').hide();
                $('#alert-message').html(msg);
                $('.messagebox').slideDown('slow');
                $("#btn").text('Please Wait...'); // a
                top.location.href = "index.php?msg=login"; //redirection
                    alert('SUCCESS');

            } else {
                $('messagebox').fadeIn(1000, function(){                        
                    $("#alert-message").html(msg).show();
                    alert('FAILED');
                }); 
                }
        }
    });
```

Register.php is as follows:

```php
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $secret = '';
    //get verify response data
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

        if($responseData->success == true) {
            //Success: do code to store your data...
            $result = true;
        } else {
          die($msg_recaptcha);
        } 
          return $result;
    }
```

If its success then it has to redirect to index.php?msg=login or else it has to show the error message. Can someone pls help me on this.

Comment: what issue are you facing? more elaborate

Comment: If its success then it has to redirect to index.php or else it has to trigger error that the captcha validation is Failed.

Answer (score 0):

Do try to send the data in the curly braces because due to `,` the code might consider the `success` as a part of data.

```
 data: {data :data1,captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()},
```

And on the PHP page you should get the name of the posted data by which you have attached your data as

```
if (isset($_POST['captcha'])) {
            $secret = '';
            //get verify response data
            $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

            $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

                    if($responseData->success == true) {
                        //Success: do code to store your data...
                        $result = true;
                    } else {
                      die($msg_recaptcha);
                    } 
                      return $result;
            }
```

Comment: Yeah i got it, still i am not able to  send the response. This line of ajax is correct?             if (msg == true) {

Comment: And one more question do you see the result in console?

Comment: I can see only the captcha response:

Comment: what is the mistake am making?

Comment: I removed the if condition in the ajax. But now if i dont check the captcha also its redirecting to index.php.

Comment: Ok fine go with if and just try the condition for is as `if(console.log(msg))`

Comment: And in your network in dev tools just check the status of ajax and let me know.

Comment: Its showing This Request has no Response Data available

Comment: i tried to send the data  in this format...data: {data :data1,captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()},

Comment: But getting error from my php page:  Notice: Undefined index: firstname in $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
i am sending the registration form post values also

Comment: I think i will remove the AJAX and try and do with normal PHP. What do you suggest?